# Why won't this PDO code INSERT?

Tags: php, pdo

```
    $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user_username, user_password, user_email) VALUES ($username, $password, $email)");
    $sql->bindParam(':user_name', $username);
    $sql->bindParam(':user_password', $password);
    $sql->bindParam(':user_email', $email);
    $sql->execute();
```

I'm trying to learn PDO rather than using mysql_ but I'm running into a problem. This doesn't seem to be inserting and I'm not sure why.

I'm not getting any error messages either so I don't know what to Google.

Also, is the $db variable being in an included file (config.php which has all the database details) a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing's first, when you're developing turn on error reporting so you can see any error messages.

```
$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
```

Executing the code you have should be producing some sort of error because you are trying to bind to parameters that don't exist. Named parameters need to start with a `:` or if you would just prefer placeholder type parameters, you can use `?` instead. When you do:

```
...VALUES ($username, $password, $email)"
```

The variables will be parsed into their actual values:

```
...VALUES (bob, $2y$14$youarehashingpasswordsright, bob@gmail.com)"
```

which of course, would be a syntax error in your SQL. Instead, you need to put their parameter names:

```
......VALUES ( :username , :password , :email )"
```

Then if that doesn't work, look at any errors being produced and make sure the queries are actually being committed.

Comment: Thanks Mike, this helped me fix the problem, which was a rather very silly type. But I learned about error reporting now.

Answer (score 3):

Try -

```
$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user_username, user_password, user_email) VALUES (:user_name, :user_password, :user_email)");
$sql->bindParam(':user_name', $username);
$sql->bindParam(':user_password', $password);
$sql->bindParam(':user_email', $email);
$sql->execute();
```

Use `:user_name, ...` in your `$db->prepare()` not `$username, ...`

Comment: Still not working but getting the same result with no errors.

Comment: Have you verified that your included `$db` has connected?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors when I input the correct information, however when I purposefully mes up the database information it spits errors at me like it should. So it's connecting fine I believe.

Comment: Are any of your fields `Primary` or `Unique` key, and are you inserting duplicate values?